# CharInSet accepting Unicode NULL character

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm reading some data from memory, and this area of memory is in Unicode. So to make one ansi string I need something like this:

```
  while CharInSet(Chr(Ord(Buff[aux])), ['0'..'9', #0]) do
    begin
      Target:= Target + Chr(Ord(Buff[aux]));
      inc(aux);
    end;
```

Where Buff is array of Bytes and Target is string. I just want keep getting Buff and adding in Target while it's 0..9, but when it finds NULL memory char (00), it just stops. How can I keep adding data in Target until first letter or non-numeric character?? The #0 has no effect.

Comment: -1. Question is not clear, and accepted answer's code is equivalent to the question's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not even bother with `CharInSet()` since you are dealing with bytes and not characters:

```
var
  b: Byte;

while aux < Length(Buff) do
begin
  b := Buff[aux];
  if ((b >= Ord('0')) and (b <= Ord('9'))) or (b = 0) then
  begin
    Target := Target + Char(Buff[aux]); 
    Inc(aux); 
  end else
    Break;
end;
```

Comment: That code is equivalent to the code in the question which apparently doesn't work. That said, it is rather unclear as to what the problem is.

Comment: My code does not rely on the compiler's implementation of `CharInSet()`. But yes, it is roughtly equivilent.  I tested the original code in XE2 and it works fine for me as-is.  `CharInSet()` handles `#0` just fine.  So the problem is likely with how `Buff` is being prepared in the first place.

Comment: I'm glad you agree with me that the code in the question is the same meaning as the code in this answer, modulo the buffer overrun protection.

Comment: @HwTrap Also, why are you adding #0 characters into the middle of the string? I just can't make this add up.

Comment: Since he is using D2012, and assuming `Target` is a `UnicodeString`, putting #0 chars in the middle would be needed to maintain proper UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Think about what Target := Target + Char(Buff[aux]); means when Buff[aux]=0

Answer (score 3):

If your data is Unicode, then I am assuming that the encoding is UTF-16. In which case you cannot process it byte by byte. A character unit is 2 bytes wide. Put the data into a Delphi string first, and then parse it:

```
var
  str: string;
....
SetString(str, PChar(Buff), Length(Buff) div SizeOf(Char));
```

Do it this way and your loop can look like this:

```
for i := 1 to Length(str) do
  if not CharInSet(str[i], ['0'..'9']) then
  begin
    SetLength(str, i-1);
    break;
  end;
```

I believe that your confusion was caused by processing byte by byte. With UTF-16 encoded text, ASCII characters are encoded as a pair of bytes, the most significant of which is zero. I suspect that explains what you were trying to achieve with your `CharInSet` call.

If you want to cater for other digit characters then you can use the `Character` unit and test with `TCharacter.IsDigit()`.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and comment. Give you +1 point, but the first answer just solved my question in simple form. Any way, thank you again!!

Comment: I can't understand how Remy's answer solves the problem. Apart from avoiding the buffer overrun in you code, it does exactly the same as your code. You stated that the data in buff is Unicode. If that is true, why would you process it byte by byte?! I wonder if you really understand what is going on here.